# Block Image loading in any Android App especially in Play Store

Tags: images

Updated:

There are many third world countries where 3G network has not encompassed their entire geography, let alone providing a satisfactory internet service. As obvious, the price for internet packs on mobile are not very much affordable to lot of folks.

Cutting the story short, there are apps like Play Store and the likes of it, whose aesthetics will be affected drastically if the images are to be stopped loading. These apps I assume are made keeping developed countries and their network infrastructure in mind.

Anyway, I still need to block the images even if the app's UI looks unpleasing. I'm looking here for a method to stop loading images in Play Store. Note that I'm not asking a different app store as a solution.

In fact, if the solution is more general (for other apps) than selective for Play Store, it would still be considered as an answer.

---

Note:

1. Device rooted, so no issues for installing any app.
2. Adaway installed but couldn't blacklist images using regex(naive) expression.
3. Firefox for Android has addons, it is already sorted for now.

Any idea(s) how to achieve this goal?

Comment: *noRoot Data firewall* has an option named *no image mode* but I didn't tested on play store.

Comment: Alternatively log in to gmail account and install apps from web version of google play.Images can be disabled in most browers or use UC brower with reduced image quality option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, that no image mode is not working in Play Store.

Comment: It's newbie app. Reporting to developer will help to fix the bug.

Comment: The Play Store uses https with certificate pinning, afaik. So stripping the images on the network level would be very difficult. Your best bet would be to modify the app, patching the image loading. You could code an Xposed module (like that one:  http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.playstorefix ). You could also try blocking lh3.googleusercontent.com where google hosts most images (that might break more stuff though).

Comment: I'll see if some host based blocking works for Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

A Christian  who developed this for [LC PlayStore](https://www.likechrist.co.za/lc-playstore-app-for-android/) for fellow Chrstians who wishes for control over images they get exposed to there. It is webview based and employs various approaches (including injecting java scripts) to try and provide a near Android native experience. Direct PlayStore like [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.likeChrist.AppStore).

Disclaimer: I am the author of the LC PlayStore app